# Custom Fonts disappear regularly in Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

The custom fonts (**Elementor (burger menu) > Site Settings > Global Fonts --> Custom Fonts**) disappear once a week or even more often.

I found out that following file is missing, when the custom fonts are missing, f.e.: /wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-15544.css

I need to regenerate the CSS-Files in WP-Dashboard > Elementor > Tools --> Regenerate CSS & Data or do a WP-preview of a site where the styles are gone.

[image]

Here are some details to my WP-setup:

```
== Server Environment ==
    Operating System: Linux
    Software: Apache
    MySQL version: mariadb.org binary distribution v10.5.18
    PHP Version: 7.4.33
    PHP Memory Limit: 512M
    PHP Max Input Vars: 3000
    PHP Max Post Size: 200M
    GD Installed: Yes
    ZIP Installed: Yes
    Write Permissions: All right
    Elementor Library: Connected

== WordPress Environment ==
    Version: 6.1.1
    Site URL: https://www.erbrechtsinfo.at
    Home URL: https://www.erbrechtsinfo.at
    WP Multisite: No
    Max Upload Size: 200 MB
    Memory limit: 40M
    Max Memory limit: 512M
    Permalink Structure: /%category%/%postname%/
    Language: de-AT
    Timezone: Europe/Vienna
    Admin Email: ***
    Debug Mode: Active
== Active Plugins ==
    All In One WP Security
        Version: 5.1.4
        Author: All In One WP Security & Firewall Team

    *** Portale
        Version: 1.1.37
        Author: ***

    Easy WP SMTP
        Version: 1.5.3
        Author: Easy WP SMTP team

    Elementor
        Version: 3.9.2
        Author: Elementor.com

    Elementor Pro
        Version: 3.9.2
        Author: Elementor.com

    Element Pack Pro
        Version: 6.11.0
        Author: BdThemes

    GDPR Cookie Compliance
        Version: 4.8.2
        Author: Moove Agency

    GDPR Cookie Compliance - Premium Add-On
        Version: 2.0.5
        Author: Moove Agency

    Imagify
        Version: 2.1
        Author: Imagify – Optimize Images & Convert WebP

    Koko Analytics
        Version: 1.0.37
        Author: ibericode

    Link Whisper
        Version: 2.1.5
        Author: Link Whisper

    Loco Translate
        Version: 2.6.3
        Author: Tim Whitlock

    Meta Box
        Version: 5.6.15
        Author: MetaBox.io

    Meta Box Group
        Version: 1.3.15
        Author: MetaBox.io

    MyListing Addons
        Version: 1.2.30
        Author: 27collective

    Rating Form
        Version: 1.6.9
        Author: Serdar Gürler

    Schema & Structured Data for WP & AMP
        Version: 1.9.108
        Author: Magazine3

    TablePress
        Version: 2.0.1
        Author: Tobias Bäthge

    WordPress Backup & Security Plugin - BlogVault
        Version: 4.86
        Author: Backup by BlogVault

    WP Rocket
        Version: 3.12.4
        Author: WP Media

    Yoast SEO
        Version: 19.13
        Author: Team Yoast


== Elementor Experiments ==
    Optimized DOM Output: Inactive
    Improved Asset Loading: Inactive
    Improved CSS Loading: Inactive
    Inline Font Icons: Inactive
    Accessibility Improvements: Inactive
    Additional Custom Breakpoints: Inactive
    Import Export Website Kit: Inactive
    Hide native WordPress widgets from search results: Inactive
    admin_menu_rearrangement: Inactive by default
    Flexbox Container: Inactive
    Default to New Theme Builder: Inactive
    Landing Pages: Inactive
    Color Sampler: Inactive
    Favorite Widgets: Inactive
    Admin Top Bar: Active by default
    Lazy Load Background Images: Inactive by default
    Save as Default: Inactive
    Page Transitions: Inactive
    Notes: Inactive
    Loop: Inactive
    Form Submissions: Active
    Scroll Snap: Inactive
```

Does anyone know what causes this issue?

Comment: Same here, also during "edit" - but refreshing the page somehow brings them back